# How to access a member of a structure

Tags: c++

I have defined `typedef std::vector<ColorInfo*> ColorInfoVector;` in the class

```
struct ColorInfo
{
    ColorInfo() : m_displayVector() {}


    // data members 
    DisplayAttrVector m_displayVector;
};
```

I am getting an input in a method as

```
void Display (ColorInfoVector                     *colorInfoVector)
```

in side the method when i try to access the member variable og the structure like below

```
DisplayAttrVector dispAttrs = (*(colorInfoVector[i]))->m_displayVector;
```

getting errors

```
error C2100: illegal indirection
error C2039: 'm_displayVector': is not a member of 'std::vector<ColorInfo *>'
```

Comment: `void Display (ColorInfoVector* colorInfoVector)` should probably be `void Display (const ColorInfoVector& colorInfoVector)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
DisplayAttrVector dispAttrs = (*((*colorInfoVector)[i]))->m_displayVector;
```

`(*colorInfoVector)[i]` gives you a pointer. To access a member of a structure using a pointer, you need to write

```
((*colorInfoVector)[i])->m_displayVector
```

or

```
(*((*colorInfoVector)[i]))).m_displayVector
```

Both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Should work like this:

```
(*colorInfoVector)[i]->m_displayVector;
```